# start-all.sh not working to run the process on slave node

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to configure multinode cluster with one master and slave in my laptop. when i ran the start-all.sh from master all daemon process running in master node but Datanode and tasktracker is not starting on slave node. Password less ssh is enabled and i can do ssh for both master and slave from my masternode without pwd but if i try to do ssh master from slave node it is asking for pwd. is this a problem for not starting daemon process in slave node? do we required password less ssh on both master and slave?

ssh slave from slave node is not asking pwd only to master it is asking. Please give me some solution why i am not able to start the process in slave node from masternode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need password-less ssh from slave to master, only from master to slave.

A few things to consider:

- Can you run hadoop locally on the slave node?
- Is the slave node included in the `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR/slaves` file of the master?
- Have you added the slave node in the `/etc/hosts` file of the master?
- Are there any error messages in the log files of the slave?
- Is the same version of hadoop installed on the same path in both machines?

Comment: Hi, slaves file is not created under conf dir. I have created that file and mentioned slave hostname, problem resolved. Thanks a lot for your help.